# Apache Flink pattern detection does not find any match

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, complex-event-processing, flink-cep, stream-processing

I am trying to catch pattern with Apache Flink CEP (Complex Event Processing) Library. I started with the following structure, and I expect to see 2 matches for ids [1,2] and [3,4]. However I see no result.

```java
public class StreamingJob {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StreamingJob.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // set up the streaming execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment
                .getExecutionEnvironment();

        ArrayList <Event> strings = new ArrayList <>();
        strings.add(new Event(0L, "room", 9));
        strings.add(new Event(1L, "room", 10));
        strings.add(new Event(2L, "garden", 11));
        strings.add(new Event(3L, "room", 12));
        strings.add(new Event(4L, "garden", 13));
        strings.add(new Event(5L, "room", 14));
        strings.add(new Event(6L, "room", 15));


        KeyedStream <Event, String> source = env.fromCollection(strings).keyBy(Event::getName);

        source.print("###-source");

        Pattern <Event, ?> pattern = Pattern. <Event>begin("room")
                .where(new SimpleCondition <Event>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(Event value) {
                        logger.info("### value: {}", value);
                        return value.getName().equals("room");
                    }
                })
                .next("garden")
                .where(new SimpleCondition <Event>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(Event value) {
                        logger.info("### value: {}", value);
                        return value.getName().equals("garden");
                    }
                });

        PatternStream <Event> patternStream = CEP.pattern(source, pattern);


        // process 
        DataStream <Alarm> result = patternStream.process(
                new PatternProcessFunction <Event, Alarm>() {
                    @Override
                    public void processMatch(
                            Map <String, List <Event>> pattern,
                            Context ctx,
                            Collector <Alarm> out) throws Exception {
                        logger.info("### pattern: {}", pattern);
                        logger.info("### ctx: {}", ctx);
                        out.collect(new Alarm(pattern.toString()));
                    }
                });

        result.print("###");

        // or select function
        patternStream.select(new PatternSelectFunction <Event, Alarm>() {
            @Override
            public Alarm select(Map <String, List <Event>> pattern) throws Exception {
                logger.info("###");
                return new Alarm(pattern.toString());
            }
        }).print("###");

        // execute program
        env.execute("Flink Streaming Java API Skeleton");
    }
}
```

The `source.print()` method is printing the source stream, and for the sink I tried both `process` and `select` methods but neither of them can print the result. Also my logs from the filter or match methods are not printed at all. I have the impression that filter functions are not even used. The `Event` and `Alarm` objects are simple pojos as follows:

```java
public class Event implements Serializable {
    Long id;
    String name;
    Integer temperature;
    //...
}

public class Alarm implements Serializable {
    String text;
    // ...
}
```

I also tried to change it to filter other fields, for example, using the temperature field, I wanted to catch `odd`-`even` number sequence but still, nothing was printed as a result.

Answer (score 4):

CEP relies on being able to sort the event stream by timestamp. This requires that you either (1) use events that have timestamps and provide a `WatermarkStrategy`, or (2) specify that you want the pattern matching to be done in ingestion order, using processing time semantics.

You can do the latter by making this small change:

```java
PatternStream <Event> patternStream = 
  CEP.pattern(source, pattern).inProcessingTime();
```